# Array to dynamic function: Use eval or not?

Tags: javascript, json, function, object, eval

Having this object:

```
// Better as array, thank you for the advice @user2864740
var rule = [
  ['User', null],
  ['filter', [{ idgroup: 95, active: true}],
  ['order_by', ['name', 'created']]
];
```

I want to create a function based on the object above. I only know two ways to do it. First one is using `eval` and making the function literal:

```
eval("User.filter({ idgroup: 95, active: true }).order_by('name', 'created')");
```

The other way is more complex and i'm not sure how to approach it yet. But the result should be something like this (With a `for/while` obviously):

```
this['User']['filter'].apply(this['User'], [{ idgroup: 95, active: true }])['order_by'].apply(this['User'], ['name', 'created']);
```

Is it worth writing a dynamic function to call the function as the second option, or is eval fast enough to solve this problem?

Comment: Aren't the object keys always `User`, `filter` and `order_by`?

Comment: @user2864740 'null' means will not be called as a function.

Comment: @Bergi the idea its to be completely dynamic.

Comment: Do not use eval() for this.  It's much too dangerous, especially if your data is coming from the outside.  Think *bash shellshock* bad: what you're proposing to do is in the same vein as that bug.

Comment: @dyoo: Well, even without `eval`, something like `[['window'], ['open', ['mydangeroussite']]]` would be devastating. You just need to put trust in the data.

Comment: What do you mean with put trust in the data. Validate what properties can be sent or not?

Comment: Either trust the source where the data (which essentially is executable) is coming from, or validate the properties and restrict them to deliberately exposed methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be written as so:

```
var rules = [ /* the set of rules */ ];

// Or whatever the first rule will invoked upon
var result = this;

// Apply each rule in turn
rules.forEach(function (rule) {
    var prop = rule[0];
    var value = rule[1];
    if (value === null) {
        // Property look-up only
        result = result[prop];
    } else {
        // Call the function with the same name and apply rule arguments
        result = result[prop].apply(result, value);
    }
});

// Use result:
console.log(result);
```

More complex rule descriptors will need more complex processing.

Comment: You can make this even shorter using `reduce`: `['filter', 'order_by'].reduce(function(prop) { /* Stuff */ return /* whatever */; }, rules["User"]);`

Comment: @user2864740 This is not valid for all cases.

Comment: The rules are very simple. Null means no function, array means function, the array can be empty.

`{
    User: [],
    filter: [],
    order_by: ['name', 'created']
}; 
// User().filter().order_by('name', 'created')`

Comment: You do not understand. You are forcing to call are the parameters. Can be adapted, but it's so far from what i want.

Comment: @user2864740 doing `for (var i in myrule) ...` i keep the correct order.

Comment: @EnZo That makes sense. Remember that total tile is relative to the number of times an operation is performed as well has how fast it can be performed - if it is only executed a dozen or a few hundred time (or even many more times spread out) then few extra millisecond will not be noticed even if it looks very slow comparatively.